# uploading image from word file on localhost is working correct but not on server

Tags: php, file-upload, ms-word

I did the work in following steps:

1. I wrote the code for reading MS word file with image in it.
2. After extracting the file path from xml code I upload the image successfully on my local server. example of xml file:- `<pic:cnvpr id="0" name="Picture 4" descr="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\tshirt\14714-yepme-s-275x340-imadpnn23zqpjqzz.jpeg"</pic:cnvpr>`
3. When I upload the word file on server and download it from the server on different PC the word file having the images as it as in starting.
4. But now when I am uploading the word file from server the file displaying same path of local server and image not uploaded.

My question is: how can I upload image of the word file on server?

After reading the xml file's description I just copy that image like this

```
$pattern2 = '/descr="(.*?)"\/>/';
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $val);
copy($str,$imagepath);
```

In other words I want to upload the file on server from my PC where I have the local path of the file.

Here is the complete code where I used `read_file_docx` function for converting the `docx` file into `xml` with some delimiters:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["name"][$value]!='' && ($ext=='docx' || $ext=='doc')){
    $rand=time();
    $fileName=$scheduleId."_".$value."_".$rand.".doc";
    $cvsId=uploadCsvForQuestion($value,$scheduleId,$fileName,$rand);
    copy(
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$value],
        "../question_csv/" .$fileName
    ); // file save in folder

    //extract data from doc file 
    $allData=read_file_docx($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$value],"r");

    // explode from question
    $rre=explode("^@@@^",$allData);

    //print_r($allData);exit;

    $pattern2 = '/descr="(.*?)"\/>/'; 

    foreach($rre as $key=>$rrevalue){
        if($key!=0){
            $remaks=explode("Remarks:",$rrevalue);
                $hint=explode("Exp:",$remaks[0]); //explode from hint.

            $ans=explode("Ans-",$hint[0]);//explode from ans.

            $option=explode("^@@^",$ans[0]);//explode from options with question.
            preg_match_all($pattern2, $hint[1], $hintmatches);

            // All images in hint will save in array then save in field
                if(is_array($hintmatches)){
                foreach($hintmatches[1] as $key=>$val){
                $str = str_replace('\\', '/', $val);
                if(file_exists( $str)){
                    $imag1=rand().basename($str);
                    $sestination="../question_image/";
                    copy($str,$sestination."".$imag1);
                    $images_hint[]=$imag1;
                }
            }
            if(is_array($images_hint)){
                $imagesHint=implode("||",$images_hint);
                $images_hint='';
            }
        }

        foreach ($option as $keys=>$valuew) {

            preg_match_all($pattern2, $valuew, $matches2);
            // All images in that section like question and option will save in array then save in field                                

            if(is_array($matches2[1])){
                                foreach($matches2[1] as $key=>$val){
                                    $str = str_replace('\\', '/', $val);
                                    if(file_exists($str)){
                                        $imag2=rand().basename($str);
                                        $sestination="../question_image/";
                                        copy($str,$sestination."".$imag2);
                                        $imagesArray[]=$imag2;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(is_array($imagesArray)){
                                        $imag=implode("||",$imagesArray);
                                        $imagesArray='';
                                }

                            }
                            $valuew = strip_tags($valuew,"<sub><sup>");
                            if($keys==0){
                                //$str11= substr($valuew,'2'); old one
                                $newQuesion=explode(".",$valuew);
                                //
                                $num=0;
                                if($newQuesion!=''){
                                    $hint = strip_tags($hint[1],"<sub><sup>");
                                    $quesionId=uploadQuestion($cvsId,$value,$scheduleId,addslashes($newQuesion[1]),$hint,$imag,$imagesHint,$imagesHint,$remaks[1]);//save question
                                    $imagesHint=''; 
                                }
                            }else{

                                uploadOption($quesionId,addslashes($valuew),$keys,$imag);//save option
                            }
                            $num++; $imag="";

                        }
                        if($ans[1]!=''){
                            uploadAnswer($quesionId,$ans[1]);//save answer
                        }   
                    }
                }

}           


function read_file_docx($filename){ 
     $striped_content = ''; 
     $content = '';
      if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename))
         return false; 
         $zip = zip_open($filename);
            if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) 
         return false; 
     while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) { 
            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;
             if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue; 
             $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
            zip_entry_close($zip_entry); 

        }
        file_put_contents('question.xml', $content); 
        $content2 = explode('<w:vertAlign w:val="subscript"/></w:rPr><w:t>', $content);
        $pattern = "/<w:vertAlign w:val=\"subscript\"\/><\/w:rPr><w:t>(.*?)<\/w:t><\/w:r>/";
        preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
        $var=array_map("strip_tags_sub",$matches[1]);
        foreach($content2 as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key!=0){
                $var1=strip_tags($var[$key]);
                $content=str_replace('<w:vertAlign w:val="subscript"/></w:rPr><w:t>'.$var1."</w:t></w:r>", $var[$key],$content);
            }
        }
        $content1 = explode('<w:vertAlign w:val="superscript"/></w:rPr><w:t>', $content);
        $pattern = "/<w:vertAlign w:val=\"superscript\"\/><\/w:rPr><w:t>(.*?)<\/w:t><\/w:r>/";
        preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matchesa);
        $var1=array_map("strip_tags_sup",$matchesa[1]);
        foreach($content1 as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key!=0){
                $varq=strip_tags($var1[$key]);
                $content=str_replace('<w:vertAlign w:val="superscript"/></w:rPr><w:t>'.$varq."</w:t></w:r>", $var1[$key],$content);
            }
        }
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', " ", $content);
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
        $allData = strip_tags($content,'<pic:cNvPr><sub><sup>');
        $allData = str_replace('(Q', "^@@@^", $allData);//saperate from question
        $allData = str_replace('1).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        $allData = str_replace('2).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        $allData = str_replace('3).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        $allData = str_replace('4).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        $allData = str_replace('5).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        $allData = str_replace('6).', "^@@^", $allData);//saperate from option
        return $allData ;
  }
```

Comment: You will need to show the code you are using.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I edited the question with complete code

Answer (score 1):

Change your image in binary data from the localhost path and after that get image from the binary data on the server.

Comment: You still must implement this on the localhost and not on the server

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to copy() a file with a path on the client, but the copy() runs on the server.
Since the file does not exist on the server you will not be able to copy it. It worked on localhost because the client and the server were simply the same filesystem.

You could implement this with a client-side code like Javascript, in which you'll submit an upload form with the local file path that you extract, and the server-side PHP code will process the uploaded image.

Comment: I am asking for solution in coding. I know that problem is exactly this. But how to overcome if multiple images occurred during each option of the question ?

Comment: You'll have to process each image path individually and upload to the server - you could read the file and send it encoded in base64 to the server with js, for example